# How to add an independent JavaScript module into another website

Tags: javascript, web-services, api

In so many service provider websites like [Google-Adsense](https://www.google.co.in/adsense/start/#/?modal_active=none), [disqus](https://disqus.com/), [Tawk.io](https://www.tawk.to/)... I have seen a common thing if we want to use their service and want to integrate it using javaScript they give you some 5 to 6 lines of javaScript code and we paste it in our website code and it starts working.

For example in Tawk.io we have this code

```
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/default';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
})();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
```

My question is how it works and how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

After looking this code I understood one thing all they are doing is they are just loading their javaScript file into our web page and using our `ID` for providing their service.

Comment: what exactly is it, that you don't understand in the code you've posted?

Comment: @_Thomas thanks,  Suppose I have created an independent module and I want to make it available for any website who want to use it. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

It create a new `script` tag and store it in `s1`.

Get the first `script` tag and store it in s0.

`s1` loads the `script` present in the url `https://embed.tawk.to/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/default` , and set an attribute `crossorigin`.

Then `s1` looks like

```
<script src='https://embed.tawk.to/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/default' crossorigin='*' charset="UTF-8" async=true></script>
```

And then add it before the first script element(`s0`).

So it will load the js file from the site and work it in your page